# ionic 2/3- tabs positioning

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-tabs

I'm developing an Ionic app using Ionic 2.
I implemented tabs in a couple of pages. But in one page, tabs need to be placed at the bottom and on other page, it needs to be positioned at top. Tabs in both these pages are different.

For example, on Page A, tabs need to placed at bottom and on Page B, it needs to be on top

In `app.module.ts`, I gave the following code

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  tabsPlacement: 'top',
  platforms: {
    android: {
      tabsPlacement: 'top'
    },
    ios: {
      tabsPlacement: 'top'
    },
    windows:
    {
      tabsPlacement: 'top'
    }
  }
}),
```

The above code, places the tabs on both pages at the top.

My question is, is there a way I can specify the tabs position specific to pages?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have two tabs component or do you want to achieve this with a single tabs page

Comment: I have two different tabs. @Mahesh Jadhav

Comment: ok so for both you need different positions right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are two different tabs to be used on two different pages you can simply use the tabsPlacement attribute on the  component to position the tabs at top or bottom of the page. Remove the tabs placement from your config and add tabsPlacement attribute on individual tabs html

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top"> // specify bottom to position at the bottom
  ...
<ion-tabs>
```